# buy and sell transactions in different trading pairs compile into one "cost"

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[image]Hi everyone,

Spreadsheets beginner here. I am trying to compile a few crypto and stock transactions into one COST value of a position. By COST I mean how much I paid for in total for current holding of a trading pair or stock, so I can compare it to current value of holding and calculate the profit/loss.

Additionally there is a bit of a problem with different currency but help for step 1) would be enough probably

I am not very good with Maths or Spreadsheets as you can tell. I searched but I couldn't see a duplicate.

Here is placeholder data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p6htTuIsIj-3GWrsbhZCnQYiiN4NXD5CwXX1_8Amx40/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry for not helping out with the problem itself (don't fully understand what the problem is), but not knowing maths or spreadsheets should maybe mean that you should be careful trading stocks and crypto.

Comment: its simple, buy low sell high!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after more research this gets you very close

```
=QUERY($A3:$F222,"select sum(D) where A='Buy' and B='BTC/USD' ")
```